# Why does dynamic binding affect the body of future?

Tags: clojure, future, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to reproduce pitfalls of dynamic vars described by Chas -  http://cemerick.com/2009/11/03/be-mindful-of-clojures-binding/.

Consider the following snippet:

```
(def ^:dynamic *dynamic-x* 10)

(defn adder [arg]
  (+ *dynamic-x* arg))

(adder 5) ;; returns 15

(binding [*dynamic-x* 20]
  (adder 5)) ;; returns 25

(binding [*dynamic-x* 20]
  @(future (adder 5))) ;; returns 25 (!)
```

Actually, I was expecting that 3rd case will return 15, as soon as adding is performed on the separate thread and current thread local value of `*dynamic-x*` (which I supposed to be 10) should be used. But, unexpectedly for me, it returns 25.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: could you provide a better title of that question?  maybe something like `why does a dynamic binding unexpectedly work with a future`

Comment: @cfrick yes, sure. was thinking about this, actually :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the design of `future` that the dynamic bindings are passed to the other threads in which the future body will be executed (Look into the source of `future`, which defers to `future-call`, which uses a function called `binding-conveyor-fn` which explicitly copies the thread-local bindings).

The motivation for this IMO is that when using `future` you want to run your computation in the same "logical thread", only you're actually doing it in another Java Thread for performance reasons.

I agree it would deserve to be explicitly documented :)

Comment: Note: the assertions on Clojure's source are as of v1.7.0

Comment: The documentation: https://clojure.org/reference/vars#conveyance